# insert code before chapter title

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

I would like to insert some code before the chapter title appears. I have defined:

```
\newcommand{\toptitle}[2]{\itshape #1 \hfill #2 \par}
```

Then, if I am writing for example:

```
\begin{document}
\toptitle{Quantum Mechanics}{15.10.2011}
\chapter{My Chapter}
\end{document}
```

the chapter title does not appear because this code precedes it. I am using the titlesec package but couldn't find a command to append code before the chapter title. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

Without using `titlesec`, you can redefine the `\@makechapterhead` command (defined in `book.cls`) which actually typesets the chapter title; you could do something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\toptitle{}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \toptitle\par
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\toptitle{{\itshape Quantum Mechanics\hfill 15.10.2011}}
\chapter{Test chapter}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the `etoolbox` package, the above redefinition can be done in a shorter way:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\toptitle{}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\if@mainmatter}{\if@mainmatter\toptitle\par}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\toptitle{{\itshape Quantum Mechanics\hfill 15.10.2011}}
\chapter{Test chapter}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi. 2 things: (1) is it possible to achive my goal only using the titlesec package, without dealing with TeX primitive? (2) in your example, is it possible to modify the \toptitle such that it would suffice to write \toptitle{Quantum Mechanics}{15.10.2011} (without design)? it means change the \patchcmd accordingly. thanks

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: How can I have `\parindent` possibility in the `\titlebar` command, if I want to insert 2-3 paragraphs in it?

Answer (score 4):

If you use a documentclass of KOMA you can use the command `\setchatperpreamble` In the following example you can see the using. You can combine `\setchapterpreamble` with the command `\dictum` which is also provided by KOMA.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\setchapterpreamble[o]{Text}
\chapter{foo}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

For more information please see the documentation.

By using the package titlesec you can define you own `toptitle` command. One suggestion is seen below

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%\titleformat{command}
%            [shape]
%            {format}
%            {label}
%            {sep}
%            {before-code}
%            [after-code]

\makeatletter
\newcommand\toptitle[1]{%
   \def\@toptitle{#1}}
\toptitle{}
\newcommand*\outputtoptitle[1][\linewidth]{%
    \ifx\@toptitle\@empty
      no Toptitle\else
      \parbox{\linewidth}{\@toptitle}\par\kern12pt\fi
}
\titleformat{\chapter}%
            {\outputtoptitle\huge\bfseries}%
            {\thechapter}%
            {12pt}%
            {}

\makeatother 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\toptitle{\lipsum[1]}
\chapter{foo}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks  but is there a solution with the book class, maybe with the titlesec package as I wrote?

Comment: @Andro: You didn't wrote any documentclass. With the package `titlesec` you can define you own style with `\titleformat`. One argument is for `precode`.

Comment: I couldn't find such an argument. Only one before the chapter title body (and after the label). Could you give a MWE?

Comment: @Andro: I edited my post

Comment: Thanks. but I would like to set the \toptitle by hand after \begin{document} every time  use a new chapter. I see there is a lot of tex programming. Is there a simple solution just with an option of the titlesec package?

Comment: @Andro: Sorry but I can not understand your problem. You have to set toptitle before a chapter starts.